# HTML file on Right-Click-> Edit opens in MS Office

Tags: windows, edit

Whenever I save any file in `.html` format and try to edit it by Right-click -> Edit, it open in ms office.

[image]

Is there any way I can change it to on click of edit option open it with notepad or Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Programs > change the HTML editor from Word to something else.

OR

Change the Default registry key under to the path of the program.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor\shell\edit\command

E.g.

"C:\Program Files\TextPad 5\TextPad.exe" -s "%1"

Comment: Thanks.. working for notepad. can i change it to Dreamweaver? I don't see any option there for Dreamweaver.

Comment: If the app is not listed in IE, only other way is to change the registry key. I've update the answer with reg key info.